# Drupal 6.10 installation problem

Tags: drupal-6

I m migrating my existing drupal site from one server  to another . I have imported the db , copied the files and changed the settings in the settings.php file. However each time I  try to run the update.php script or install.php script .. instead of showing some drupal screen the file ends up getting downloaded. Could any one please point out what is it that I m doing wrong. Any help on this would be appreciated . Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue had nothing to do with the Drupal installation. The problem was at the server end where the permissions have been reset.

Comment: The cause of the problem is some issue with the .htacess file. Fixing dat fixes the issue. The site is running now :)

Answer (score 0):

It might be that your server either doesn't support php or doesn't have it enabled. That could cause the file to be downloaded as the server is not interpreting it, just serving it to your browser.

Comment: Thanks for answering .. But the server does support php and also had it enabled . The root of the problem lied with the .htaccess file.